# Unable to download/ save audio files- I can only listen but not save the file

Tags: downloads

I am unable to save/ download audio files. I am using firefox browser on ubuntu OS and all these days did not have a problem downloading audio files.  Since the last software update....I am unable to download or save files.   Please HELP.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on the audio file link and then select "Save Link As" option.
- Give a name for that file and then select save.Now your firefox browser will automatically starts to download that audio file.