# How to save/download an audio/sound file from internet? (not from Youtube)

Tags: firefox, pulseaudio, downloads

I cannot figure out how to download a sound file (public radio show) from the Internet. I am using Firefox with Ubuntu 14.04. Do you by any chance have experience grabbing non-Youtube sound files (not sure about format) from the Internet? Take a look below for details about this issue; if I omitted any information you need, please let me know, and I will provide it. Thanks in advance.

Links related to my problem:

1. This page contains the link which launches the page on which the radio show can be heard: http://www.cbc.ca/radio/thecurrent/the-current-for-january-5-2016-1.3389695/lessons-from-isis-defectors-on-how-to-fight-indoctrination-1.3389810
2. This page contains the sound file, and controls for listening (play, pause, etc...) http://www.cbc.ca/radio/popup/audio/listen.html?autoPlay=true&clipIds=&mediaIds=2681480692&contentarea=radio&subsection1=radio1&subsection2=currentaffairs&subsection3=the_current&contenttype=audio&title=2016/01/05/1.3389810-lessons-from-isis-defectors-on-how-to-fight-indoctrination&contentid=1.3389810

Attempts to solve problem (without any luck):

1. I tried to use trusty "ClipGrab" which is usually fantastic, but it cannot find any down-loadable material on either of the 2 links provided above.
2. I tried following this advice and saving all the files associated with the page, but I had no luck (no audio file was saved - only *.html):
   [Unable to download/ save audio files- I can only listen but not save the file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438907/unable-to-download-save-audio-files-i-can-only-listen-but-not-save-the-file)
3. I saw this and got really excited, but it didn't fly. My interpretation of the terminal is that is found one file, downloaded it and deleted it. [How to download audio from web page other then youtube from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557761/how-to-download-audio-from-web-page-other-then-youtube-from-command-line)

[image]

Comment: Give it a try with Ctrl+F5 to make sure it will really reload. And then make sure you check the "All" filter in the bottom bar. It must be there somewhere if it is playing.

Comment: @Jakuje I will spend some time playing with firefox to figure this out. I can see in your image, what I should see, so I'm going to figure out how to get there. when I do, I will accept your answer. Thanks for your help, and I will keep you in the loop. A big massive thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common practice is to open "Developer Tools" in Firefox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), go to "Network" tab, reload a page and then find the appropriate file that is being downloaded (usually the largest, MP3/MPEG) and then "Copy URL" from the right click menu on the file.

Then you can download it using you favorite downloader or in the another Firefox tab.

[image: dev. panel in Firefox]

Comment: Hi, first off thank you for taking the time to help. I followed your instructions, but I cannot find any MP3/MPEG files in the 'Type' column. Any suggestions?

Comment: In my screenshot, it is the last one. Or does your screen look different?

Comment: I am working on putting up a picture in the post... give me 5 seconds. Thanks :-)

Comment: I put the images up in the post. I have never used the developer tools in Firefox, maybe I need to select some option that you have enabled in your browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks!! I followed your instructions very closely and everything worked. The key here was to follow your directions very closely and not to miss any steps! Thanks a bunch for teaching me how to overcome this problem. Have a nice weekend :-)